# mouse cursor blink on 14.04 live on cool drive

Tags: mouse, 14.04, cursor

I make my cool drive boot able and I use Ubuntu 14.04 on my cool drive but my mouse cursor blinks? even I do not run any heavy process. what is the problem? Bye the way **I do not have black screen** . every thing seems normal except mouse cursor which blinks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go in settings -> Display, and you will probably see two active monitors: disable the one which is unknown and click apply.

Answer (score 2):

In ubuntu 14.04 with a Dell XPS L502X installed nvidia drive. That did fix the problem. Only turn-off Unknown Display not solved.

another article on this subject
[Mouse cursor blinking after Ubuntu 14.04 installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454930/course-blinking-after-ubuntu-14-04-installation)