# Mouse cursor blinking after Ubuntu 14.04 installation

Tags: mouse, cursor, gpu-driver

I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04.  The mouse cursor won't stop blinking, and sometimes disappears. I've seen some other posts, but they're all about Ubuntu 12.04 or 13.10.

Comment: Bug report of something real similar : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1278223

Answer (score 28, accepted):

- Do **System Settings > Displays**
- And **turn-off** / **disable** Unknown Display.

Comment: thank you, but there is no unknown display. there are two displays - two so called built-in-displays. one marked with a pink colour and another with a green one.

Comment: problem solved. disable one of the displays. if the screen goes black, reboot the computer, and disable the other one. after that it should work properly. if the screen does not go black, you disabled the right display. then you've already solved it (in principle).

Comment: if your question is solved then mark it as **Answered**

Comment: i'm sorry but, how do i do that? i'm new to this

Comment: Just tick the correct mark that will come beside the answer to make it green. and make answer accepted. Check the askubuntu guide http://askubuntu.com/about

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks. However, I was wondering what is the issue here? It detects multiple displays even if I have one?

Comment: same problem with me but I've only one display. There is no unknown monitors. what should I do? @Back.Slash

Comment: This answer pointed me in the right direction. Simply pressing "Apply" then "Keep this configuration" did the trick on Ubuntu 16.04 with two external monitors (one USB powered)