# Mouse flickering again

Tags: mouse, display

The first time mouse flickered i was told to change display settings, and i did and no more flickering. But the mouse flickering problem has now come back for some reason. Everything was good these last few months. So i really don't know how to solve this problem anymore. Can somebody please help me?.

Comment: Can you please give more information? For example: what exactly did you do the first time? A link to the answer you followed would be awesome. what version of ubuntu are you on? What is your graphics card? The more information we have, the bigger chance we can help you.

Comment: I was following  this answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/454930/mouse-cursor-blinking-after-ubuntu-14-04-installationI . But now i seem to have solved he problem. I installed the intel graphics driver on my ubuntu. 14.04 and the mouse flickering went away. I was using ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650

Comment: I had a problem with screen flickering on mouse movement over graphics programs on my HP laptop, the fix was to connect a new monitor, in this case my TV. and turn off laptop screen in the display program.

Answer (score 0):

visual glitches like a flickering mouse cursor are most of the time caused by bad graphics drivers. Try to install the latest driver using the "additional drivers" app.