# why my mouse pointer is blinking and suddenly disapear

Tags: mouse

recently I have installed the new ubuntu 15.04 and my pointer starts to blink and when I open an application it disapear. Can someone try to help fix this bug?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mouse cursor blinking after Ubuntu 14.04 installation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/454930/mouse-cursor-blinking-after-ubuntu-14-04-installation)

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem after upgrading to 15.04. I searched and found an answer. Now my problem was solved. I think that can also be an answer for u.

Do System **Settings** > **Displays**
And **turn-off** / **disable** Unknown Display.

[Mouse cursor blinking after Ubuntu 14.04 installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454930/mouse-cursor-blinking-after-ubuntu-14-04-installation)

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers on different questions. It just creates more work for the moderators. If the questions are so similar that the same answer works on each, then the later of the two is likely a duplicate and should be flagged as such.